# Delete record from many to many relation with extra column

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 2 entites and 1 entity is a mapping table:

```
Group:

package com.gamescheduler.gameconfigservice.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "groups")
public class Group extends BaseEntity {
    public Group(String name, String description, int maxPlayers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
    }

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Date updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "max_players", columnDefinition = "int default 130")
    private int maxPlayers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<GroupMembership> groupMemberShips;
}

User:
package com.gamescheduler.gameconfigservice.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.*;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Table(name = "players", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "user_id")})
@Entity
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Player extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @NotNull(message = "User ID cannot be null")
    private Long userId;

    @NotNull(message = "First name cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "First name cannot be empty")
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull(message = "Last name cannot be null")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name cannot be empty")
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Max(120)
    @Min(14)
    @Column
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "skill_rating", nullable = false)
    @DecimalMax("5.0")
    @DecimalMax("1.0")
    private double skillRating;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "player")
    private Set<GroupMembership> groupMemberShips;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "player_field",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "player_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "field_id"))
    private Set<Field> fields;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private Date creationDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Date updatedDate;
}


GroupMembership:
package com.gamescheduler.gameconfigservice.domain.model;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@Table(name = "group_players_mapping", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"group_id", "player_id"}))
public class GroupMembership extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    private Player player;

    @Column(name = "is_admin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

}
```

I am getting this error while trying to delete group:

"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fk494h59b0ue2wl0j5s1tmtk02f]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"

I understand that the error caused because I am trying to delete group but there is a record with the same id inside the group membership table. But why the cascade not working? In my mind that when I am deleting Group so automaticly the record will deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using cascade in the wrong entity. If you want to delete parent entity (**Group**) along with child entity (**GroupMembership**), you need to use like this in the **Group** class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<GroupMembership> groupMemberShips;
```

Actually, `CascadeType.REMOVE` does the job, it is up to you.